# I am getting " org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:" when clicking "Addtocart" link in Flipkart Site using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am unable to click Add to cart link in this Flipkart site

I am getting " org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:" when clicking "Addtocart" link in Flipkart Site using selenium webdriver

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Sample {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-j7-6-new-2016-edition/p/itmegmrnggh56u22?pid=MOBEG4XWDK4WBGNU&al=5%2Fv2LfAd8f%2F5738uEXqULMldugMWZuE7Qdj0IGOOVqv3euFa7evSptHq1kfBhuSDZH5Pp6sYgwI%3D&ref=L%3A2032472314537789506&srno=b_1");


            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
             wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add to Cart']")));


         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add to Cart']")).click();     


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should click on button (`input`), not the form itself:

```
...
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add to Cart']")).click();
```

If page takes some time to load, you may need to wait for button to become clickable first, and then click it:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
    .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
        By.xpath("//input[@value='Add to Cart']"))
    .click();
```

Comment: Still i get the same exception.. As suggested by you, i have given the button(input) and also given webdriverwait. still i am getting webdriverexception. Please guide. I have edited my question where you can see my edited code.

Comment: what does exception say?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (705.5, 21.199996948242188). Other element would receive the click: <span class="vmiddle"></span>
Command duration or timeout: 982 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-Q7EG31K', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: hmm.. 705.5, 21.199996948242188 coordinates suggest that for some reason Add to Cart button shows up at the same place as top menu. But I can't see it happening. I also don't see ` <span class="vmiddle"></span>` element (although there are elements like ` <span class="vmiddle">Advertise</span> `. What's the resolution of the screen? What if you don't maximize window?

Comment: I have tried with not maximizing the window, still not working @Kiril S. And my screen resolution is 1366 x 768. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a div is showing up when you are trying to click the button. At the moment, that div (vmiddle) is hidden.
It seems like this, when I disable the hidden:

[image]

Try to debug on your ide first. When you see that this div is in front of your "add to cart" button, try this:
1. If that is a popup and can be closed, close it and click add to cart
2. If not, try to scroll down and click the button when you see it.

scroll method can be like
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");

Comment: I tried using JavaScriptExecutor, still not working. Any solution?

Comment: Sorry, I can't give you any more solution because I cannot reproduce your problem. Are you sure there is nothing on the screen like popup when you are trying to click to button?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

Using JavaScriptExecutor I have clicked the Button. Thanks for the support. Below is the working code.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptExecutor;

public class Flipkart {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        // driver.manage().window().maximize();
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-j7-6-new-2016-edition/p/itmegmrnggh56u22?pid=MOBEG4XWDK4WBGNU&al=5%2Fv2LfAd8f%2F5738uEXqULMldugMWZuE7Qdj0IGOOVqv3euFa7evSptHq1kfBhuSDZH5Pp6sYgwI%3D&ref=L%3A2032472314537789506&srno=b_1");
         Thread.sleep(3000);
         jsclick(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add to Cart']")));

    public static void jsclick(WebElement element){
         JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
         js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element);


    }

}
```